# Display a hyperlink in Visual Studio test explorer output window

Tags: visual-studio

Using visual studio 2019.

I write test log using `TestContext.WriteLine(String^...)`, and sometimes show path to files on the disk as output.

`Writeline(L"file://C:/file.txt")` will display the text with underscore, colored in blue, as if it was a hyperlink. However, it won't be clickable.

Here is the output:
[image: Here is the output]
"file://C:/file.txt" text looks like a hyperlink but is not clickable. What should I do to be able to click it?